# WordPress Mobile Menu and Internal Links

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

I have a mobile menu which has some internal and external page links. If I click on the external page link, the menu closes.

However, if I click on the internal link, it scrolls to the relevant section but the menu doesn't close.

I believe this is because of the 'reload' performed when you change pages that doesn't happen on internal links.

I thought I could add a page reload to the internal links but I can't see a way of doing this.

I have put together a test site to illustrate the issue - http://showcase.wearelens.co.uk

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do? it's normal behaviour that if you click on an external link the page reloads, clicking `contact-us` reloads the page so the menu will be closed. On the homepage, you will need to use javascript to close the menu if it is an internal link, use custom class or attributes to target those links.

Comment: I have finally worked out with a combination of css and jquery. Thanks